# why "and" can not be operation within accumulate in Racket-lang?

Tags: racket

```lisp
#lang racket

(define (accumulate op initial sequence)
  (if (null? sequence)
      initial
      (op (car sequence)
          (accumulate op initial (cdr sequence)))))

(define (all-is-true? items)
  (accumulate and
              true
              items))

(all-is-true? (list true true true))
```

the output is:

```
 and: bad syntax in: and
```

I cannot find why the "and" procedure cannot be the operation of accumulate.

Answer (score 4):

`and` is a macro. In this example you can fix your code by writing:

```
(define (all-is-true? items)
  (accumulate (lambda (a b) (and a b))
              true
              items))
```

Macros can not be passed as arguments. They can only appear as the car of an application.

Comment: +1. Note that it's not *always* safe to replace `and` with `(lambda (a b) (and a b))`, because the former has short-circuiting behavior while the latter does not (which is why `and` is implemented how it is to begin with). In the OP's example, short-circuiting is irrelevant at the point where `and` is used; but this does raise the point that it would probably be better to implement `all-is-true?` in a short-circuiting way rather than using `accumulate`.